# How to update a date column from column with weeks

Tags: sql-server, date, week-number

I need to set the date to Monday of the week set in the week column

I created a query where there are differences:

```
select PROD_NR, BEWERK_DAT, BEWERK_WK, DATEPART(wk , BEWERK_DAT) as WeekIndex from Table1 where status = 3 and RIGHT(bewerk_wk,2) <> DATEPART(wk , BEWERK_DAT) order by id desc
```

Part of the output is like this:

```
PROD_NR BEWERK_DAT  BEWERK_WK   WeekIndex
P34619  2020-03-02  2020-09     10
P34619  2020-03-02  2020-09     10
P34619  2020-03-02  2020-09     10
P34619  2020-02-28  2020-08     9
P34619  2020-02-27  2020-08     9
```

I need to update the BEWERK_DAT column according to the week in BEWERK_WK

Output should be like:

```
PROD_NR BEWERK_DAT  BEWERK_WK   WeekIndex
P34619  2020-02-24  2020-09     9
P34619  2020-02-24  2020-09     9
P34619  2020-02-24  2020-09     9
P34619  2020-02-17  2020-08     8
P34619  2020-02-17  2020-08     8
```

Something like:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET bewerk_dat = "monday of the week part from BEWERK_WK" where there are differences.
```

Answer (score 1):

The following may give you what you are looking for.  I have provided a SELECT as well as the UPDATE.

The SET DATEFIRST is setting the first of the week to Monday

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

---
SELECT PROD_NR, BEWERK_DAT,  BEWERK_WK ,  WeekIndex, CAST(SUBSTRING(BEWERK_WK,1,4) AS int) NewYear, CAST(SUBSTRING(BEWERK_WK,6,2) as int) NewWeek
 ,dateadd (week, CAST(SUBSTRING(BEWERK_WK,6,2) as int), dateadd (year, CAST(SUBSTRING(BEWERK_WK,1,4) AS int)-1900, 0)) - 4 -
     datepart(dw, dateadd (week, CAST(SUBSTRING(BEWERK_WK,6,2) as int), dateadd (year, CAST(SUBSTRING(BEWERK_WK,1,4) AS int)-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1
FROM Table1
WHERE  CAST(SUBSTRING(BEWERK_WK,6,2) as int)  <> WeekIndex

--- 
UPDATE Table1 SET BEWERK_DAT = dateadd (week, CAST(SUBSTRING(BEWERK_WK,6,2) as int), dateadd (year, CAST(SUBSTRING(BEWERK_WK,1,4) AS int)-1900, 0)) - 4 -
     datepart(dw, dateadd (week, CAST(SUBSTRING(BEWERK_WK,6,2) as int), dateadd (year, CAST(SUBSTRING(BEWERK_WK,1,4) AS int)-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1
WHERE  CAST(SUBSTRING(BEWERK_WK,6,2) as int)  <> WeekIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way myself after a few hours more of searching.

```
set datefirst 1
go
update Table1 set BEWERK_DAT = CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, CONVERT(int, RIGHT(bewerk_wk,2)) - 1,DATEADD(dd, 1 - DATEPART(dw, '1/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),CONVERT(int, LEFT(bewerk_wk,4)))), '1/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),CONVERT(int, LEFT(bewerk_wk,4))))) as date)
where status = 3 and RIGHT(bewerk_wk,2) <> DATEPART(wk , BEWERK_DAT)
```

and before I could do this I had some fields in BEWERK_WK with a 9999-99 value which I had to reset first

```
update Table1 set BEWERK_WK = CONCAT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(year, BEWERK_DAT)), '-', CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(wk, BEWERK_DAT))) where bewerk_wk like '9%'
```